# iOS - Force a UIWebView to load content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I set the content of a `UIWebView` using `loadHtmlString:`. I don't add them to the `UIView` until they are need, but I need to know the max scroll height of each of them.

The problem is that `UIWebView` doesn't start loading it's data until it's added to a `superView`, and It's the delay of loading content that is causing this problem.

**Question:** Is it possible to force a `UIWebView` to load its content, without being added to a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the view and set it's opacity to 0.01 to force the load. I've had to do this with MKMapView before.

Comment: I am dealing with dynamic data, and i might end up with up to 400 UIWebViews added to my UIView, It's gonna cause performance hit

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `hidden` property of `UIWebView` - setting it to `YES` before view is added and clearing it to `NO` in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` should do the trick.

However, you comment to @logancautrell's answer is a bit unsettling - do you ever plan to get that many web views added to your views? I assume you know that, but just in case: depending on your possible HTML(5)/JavaScript/CSS code, you may observe severe performance hit even with a small number of web views for which iOS needs to allocate lots of resources.

If you plan to update your web views often, maybe you could benefit from UIWebView's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method? To some extent, the performance hit can be bearable, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, setting hidden. The web view will not load unless it is visible on the screen. This is the same problem with MKMapView, which is where my little work around came from. Setting the opacity to 0.0 has the same affect as hidden=YES, it won't work. At least it didn't in iOS 4.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest either pre-calculating the scroll heights somehow (not during web view load), or finding a way to display your UIViews without waiting for the scroll heights initially, and correct them later.